# Javascript: How do I add a line feed to this code for a textarea field

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("hi2").value = arrayd[i] + document.getElementById("hi2").value + ',';
```

hi2 is a TEXTAREA

When I fill the textarea with the array I don't know how to add a space after every item in the array.

This is the END Result Im looking for:

```
Jill
Bob
Tony
Nancy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to insert a newline in between each array element

```
document.getElementById("hi2").value = arrayd.join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <textarea id="hi2"></textarea>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var arrayd = ['Jill', 'Bob', 'Tony', 'Nancy'];
         document.getElementById("hi2").value = arrayd.join("\n");
     </script>
```